# Overwritting a section partially

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In `config/config.exs` I have this:

```
  config :my_config_section, MyApp.Module1,
    a: "dfsafds",
    b: 1234,
    c: "aaaaaa",
    d: true
```

In `config/dev.exs` I want to overwritte only 1-2 keys `:my_config_section`. Without having to specify all the keys again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation for [`Mix.config/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Config.html#config/3)

> Keyword lists are always deep merged.

So yes, just overwrite keys you want, assuming you invoke `import_config "dev.exs"` *after* the generic `config` call.

Comment: alekseika, chto za shlyapa na tvoiey golove? siniaya